# Why doesn't applyBindings work sometimes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I've got a simply html page that I dynamically create on the client side using jquery, jqueryui and knockout and some data from a web service.

I dynamically create some tags with some code like this:

```
document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = dynamicTags;
```

and after that I call ko.applyBindings:

```
ko.applyBindings(Datas, document.getElementById("myDiv"));
```

This simply doesn't work; no exceptions are raised in the chrome debugger.

I've done some random tests with this code:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    ko.applyBindings(Datas, document.getElementById("myDiv"));
}, 3000);
```

Everything works perfectly.

Why does this happen? I bind values and styles at the same time.

This code is called by a button click!

Comment: Are you using virtual elements? Also, setup a jsfiddle.

Comment: can you jsfiddle this ?

Comment: [I don't see an issue](http://jsfiddle.net/5XfDT/1/)

Comment: ...[even with button click](http://jsfiddle.net/5XfDT/2/) (per comment to answer below).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chances are your code isn't being executed (or bound to be executed) because it works [with](http://jsfiddle.net/5XfDT/2/) and [without](http://jsfiddle.net/5XfDT/1/) clicking a button from my eyes.

```
function goLetsGo(){
    var html = '<fieldset>'
        + '<legend data-bind="text:fullname"></legend>'
        + '<p>First Name: <span data-bind="text:firstname"></p>'
        + '<p>Last Name: <span data-bind="text:lastname"></p>'
        + '<p>Age: <span data-bind="text:age"></p>'
    + '</fieldset>';

    document.getElementById('myDiv').innerHTML = html;

    var vm = function(){
        this.firstname = ko.observable('Brad');
        this.lastname = ko.observable('Christie');
        this.fullname = ko.computed(function(){
            return this.firstname() + ' ' + this.lastname();
        }, this);
        this.age = 27;
    };
    ko.applyBindings(new vm(), document.getElementById('myDiv'));
}
```

Results in:

```
<fieldset>
  <legend data-bind="text:fullname">Brad Christie</legend>
  <p>First Name: <span data-bind="text:firstname">Brad</span></p>
  <p>Last Name: <span data-bind="text:lastname">Christie</span></p>
  <p>Age: <span data-bind="text:age">27</span></p>
</fieldset>
```

Check to make sure the code's being called. Also, confirm you don't have any binding errors (such as referencing a property that doesn't exist, or trying to use an undeclared binding).

Comment: I found the answer by myself: simply in my function i was calling a service and some generation code was written in the response of this call. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 3):

Ensure that you are applying your binding either in a script that is at the end of your DOM or  when your DOM has been loaded. In jQuery, this can be done with the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // apply bindings here
});
```

Otherwise, script that is inline might be invoked before the HTML has been fully loaded into memory or even downloaded.

Comment: sorry, I forgot to say that this script is called by a button click!

Comment: are you sure it's called?

Comment: Yes, i generate a lot of tags that was render in browser's window and in the same function i call ko.applyBindings.